# Ror creating table association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a table and now I want to add an association (has_many relationship) to the table. How can I do it if I have already created a table and rake db:migrate has been done after creation of model?

Is it possible to add association (has_many relation) in a table after it's creation in ror?

Comment: If you post the names of the models I can give you the exact command to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use migrations to add the column that connects the two tables. Take care on the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyModel has_many :foos`, then there's actually no column relating to that relation in the `my_models` table. Instead, you will need to create the `Foo` model with a `my_model_id` column, or generate a migration to add that column to the existing `foos` table.

That is, you want to run either:

```
rails generate model Foo <other fields> my_model_id:integer
```

or

```
rails generate migration add_my_model_id_to_foo my_model_id:integer
```

Note that the syntax about is for Rails 3; under Rails 2, you need `ruby script\generate ...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your terminal, do the following:

```
rails generate migration AddColumnToTableName column_id:integer
```

Replace `TableName` with the name of the table you need to add the column to and `column` with the name of the model that gets the `belong_to` association.